Where does the characteristic polynomial live?
In Linear Algebra by Friedberg, the author defines

Let $A\in M_{n\times n}(F)$. The polynomial $f(t)=\det(A-tI_n)$ is called the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

I don't have any problem about thinking of $\det(A-tI_n)$ as a polynomial with coefficients in $F$, i.e., an element of $F[t]$. But Friedberg also makes the following clarification about its definition

The observant reader may have noticed that the entries of the matrix $A-tI_n$ are not scalars in the field $F$. They are, however, scalars in another field $F(t)$, the field of quotients of polynomials in $t$ with coefficients from $F$. Consequently, any results proved about determinants in Chapter $4$ remain valid in this context.

I think I understand why the author makes an effort to clarify this, strictly speaking, $t$ is acting as a variable, not as an element of $F$, then the matrix $A-tI_n$ is not a matrix of scalars from $F$.
I just know the basic things about abstract algebra. If I understood it correctly, by $F(t)$ means $F[t]/ \langle t \rangle$, where $\langle t \rangle$ is the ideal generated by the polynomial $t$ and we make the identification of $F[t]$ in $F[t]/ \langle t \rangle$ by $\alpha(t)\rightarrow \alpha(t) + \langle t\rangle$. If
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
then the matrix $A-tI_n$ [viewed as a matrix with coefficients in $F[t]/ \langle t \rangle$] is
$$A -tI =
\begin{pmatrix}
2-t + \langle t \rangle & 0 + \langle t \rangle\\
1 + \langle t \rangle & 1-t + \langle t \rangle
\end{pmatrix}$$
with determinant
$$\det(A-tI) = \left[2-t + \langle t \rangle\right]\left[1-t + \langle t \rangle\right] = (2-3t + t^2) + \langle t \rangle$$
But wouldn't this imply that the characteristic polynomial is not well defined? Since
$$\det(A-tI) = (2-3t + t^2) + \langle t \rangle = 2 + \langle t \rangle$$
In the other hand, a different approach is to consider the matrix $A - tI_n$ as a matrix with polynomials as coefficients, i.e., an element of $M_{n\times n}(F[x])$ and extend the definition of determinant to matrices with coefficients from some integral domain (according to Wikipedia this is a set where all the usual determinant properties remain). Even we can thing the characteristic polynomial as the polynomial function $f(t) = \det(A-tI_n)$, but only when the field $F$ is infinite.
I know that in almost all (probably all) contexts these distinctions are irrelevant, but if we would like to get into the details, where we would say that the characteristic polynomial live? In $F[t]$ or $F[t]/\langle t\rangle$ or a polynomial function.

I suggest using the polynomial ring $\mathbb F[t]$ as you've intuited in your 2nd to last paragraph.  This allows easy substitution (/evaluation) homomorphisms $\phi : \mathbb F[t]\longrightarrow \mathbb F$ including a non-trivial option of $\phi(t)=0$, something that cannot work if $t$ is a unit (in a field).  A better but still very simple explanation is for you to evaluate $\det\big(A-tI)$ the same way whether it is in $\mathbb F[t]$ or $\mathbb F(t)$ since they only require ring operations in $\mathbb F[t]$ but $\mathbb F(t)$ is a field so you know what the determinant will "look like".

Actually, the field $F(t)$ is not a quotient of $F[t]$ by an ideal, but is its "field of fractions" (sometimes confusingly called  quotient field).
This is the set of expressions (or rational functions)
$$
\frac{p(t)}{q(t)},
$$
where $p(t), q(t) \in F[t]$ and $q(t)$ is not the zero polynomial, and two fractions are considered equal if we get equality after clearing denominators (in symbols, $p/q = r/s \Leftrightarrow ps = qr$).
In particular, there is an inclusion $F[t] \subset F(t)$ (identify a polynomial with the fraction whose numerator is that polynomial and whose denominator is $1$) and so you can think of a matrix with coefficients in $F[t]$ as having coefficients in the field $F(t)$.
I think this will clear up everything else that was bothering you but let me know if there are remaining questions.

Thanks, this was helpful.
